# How do I know if an ArrayList contains a specific items in mongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am using `Morphia` driver on the top of `MongoDB`. My `pojo` is as follow:

```
public class User {
  @Id private ObjectId objectId;
  @NotNull private long id;
  private List<Long> objectId;
  ....
  ....
```

However I need to write search `query` on the basis of given parameters. I created sample method:

```
 public List<User> search(String id, String objectId){
    Query<User> userInfoQuery = datastore.find(User.class);
    userInfoQuery.field("id").equal(Long.parseLong(s.trim()));
    ....
```

Above query is working fine. What should I need to add here to search in the `ArrayList`?

Comment: btw, using @NotNull on a long doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : `userInfoQuery.field("objectId").equal(Long.parseLong(s.trim()));`